# PLZ help! how to make the app save what the user write in edittext?

Tags: android-edittext, save, sharedpreferences

As shown in my picture, I want to save what the user writes as note.  So, when the user reopens the app, the notes he wrote will stay under the calendar, btw i used EditText Multiline

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcMcJ.jpg

```js
package com.example.test;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText editText;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    private static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME= "mypref";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText=findViewById(R.id.editTextTextMultiLine);

        sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME ,MODE_PRIVATE);

        String name = sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_NAME,null);


        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(KEY_NAME, editText.getText().toString());
        editor.apply();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should move `editor.clear()` below `editor.commit()`